# Getting the most frequent value of an array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an Array of numbers and I want to know which number is most frequent in this array. The array sometimes has 5-6 integers, sometimes it has 10-12, sometimes even more - also the integers in the array can be different. So I need a function which can work with different lengths and values of an array.

One example:

```
myArray = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Another example:

```
myArray = [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2]
```

Now I am searching for a function which gives out 0 (in the first example) as `Integer`, as it is 3 times in this array and the other integer in the array (1) is only 2 times in the array. Or for the second example it would be 4.

It seems pretty simple, but I cannot find a solution for this. Found some examples in the web, where the solution is to work with dictionaries or where the solution is simple - but I cannot use it with Swift 3 it seems...

However, I did not find a solution which works for me. Someone has an idea how to get the most frequent integer in an array of integers?

Comment: For something more concise than `for`, take a look into `map` and other higher order functions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
let myArray = [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2]

// Create dictionary to map value to count   
var counts = [Int: Int]()

// Count the values with using forEach    
myArray.forEach { counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }

// Find the most frequent value and its count with max(by:)    
if let (value, count) = counts.max(by: {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
    print("\(value) occurs \(count) times")
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 4 occurs 4 times
> ```

---

Here it is as a function:

```
func mostFrequent(array: [Int]) -> (value: Int, count: Int)? {
    var counts = [Int: Int]()

    array.forEach { counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }

    if let (value, count) = counts.max(by: {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
        return (value, count)
    }

    // array was empty
    return nil
}

if let result = mostFrequent(array: [1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5]) {
    print("\(result.value) occurs \(result.count) times")    
}
```

> ```
> 1 occurs 3 times
> ```

---

**Update for Swift 4:**

Swift 4 introduces `reduce(into:_:)` and default values for array look ups which enable you to generate the frequencies in one efficient line.  And we might as well make it generic and have it work for any type that is `Hashable`:

```
func mostFrequent<T: Hashable>(array: [T]) -> (value: T, count: Int)? {

    let counts = array.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }

    if let (value, count) = counts.max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 }) {
        return (value, count)
    }

    // array was empty
    return nil
}

if let result = mostFrequent(array: ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"]) {
    print("\(result.value) occurs \(result.count) times")
}
```

> > ```
> > a occurs 3 times
> > ```

Comment: Works, thank you my friend! I did find something like that which did not work, but this one works fantastic.

Comment: @vacawama How would this work if myArray had CGPoints? I am getting the error `Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`

Comment: @Hilarious404, I see you already asked a new question, which is a good idea since it is a new question.  I was going to suggest how to make CGPoint Hashable which is what MartinR's post does.  I would suggest you try that.

Comment: @vacawama hey, nice algorithm, but how would you solve this if 2 diff numbers are repeadted equally or if there aren't any repeating nums: var equallyRepeatedArr = [0, 1, 1, 2 , 2, 4] or var noRepeatingArr = [0, 7, 18, 20]

Comment: Hi vacawama , could you please elaborate the execution of this -> arr.forEach {
    counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1
    print(counts[$0])
}

Comment: @Vyankatesh, the forEach loop executes for each item in the array and runs the following closure.  Inside the closure, the current item being operated on is called `$0`.  The `counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1` updates the count for that item.  First it looks up the item's current count with `counts[$0]` which returns `nil` if the item isn't in the dictionary, or `Optional(count)` if it is.  The nil coalescing operator `??` unwraps that value if it exists or replaces it with `0` if it does not.  Then it adds one and stores it back in the dictionary.  Final result, dictionary with counts.

Answer (score 32):

You can also use the `NSCountedSet`, here's the code

```
let nums = [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2]
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: nums)
let mostFrequent = countedSet.max { countedSet.count(for: $0) < countedSet.count(for: $1) }
```

*Thanks to @Ben Morrow for the smart suggestions in the comments below.*

Comment: Thank you ! Did not know about CountedSet until now, great hint. :-)

Comment: @appzYourLife Can you explain why both elements in the lesser-than comparison are `$0.0`? I would expect them to be `$0` and `$1`. This is the example in the header file for `max(by:)`: let hues = ["Heliotrope": 296, "Coral": 16, "Aquamarine": 156]; let greatestHue = hues.max { a, b in a.value < b.value }; print(greatestHue); // Prints "Optional(("Heliotrope", 296))"

Comment: @BenMorrow: Yes you can also use `$0` and `$1`. But since the param of `max` is a tuple of 2 elements you can use `$0.0` and `$0.1` too. I'm going to use the `$0 and $1` syntax as you suggested since it is more clear, but the result doesn't change.

Comment: @appzYourLife Cool  I also thought of another optimization. You can call `max(by:)` on `countedSet` instead of `nums`. That way, it only has to run each unique element once, instead of running through all the elements in `nums`. That change will yield results 10 times faster: 0.001598 seconds vs  0.013010 seconds. Just learned the sweet [benchmarking trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115192/should-i-prefer-joined-or-flatmap-in-swift-3/39130099#39130099)

Comment: @BenMorrow: you mean this? `countedSet.max { countedSet.count(for: $0) < countedSet.count(for: $1) }`

Comment: @appzYourLife Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 10):

The most frequent value is called the "mode". Here's a concise version:

```
let mode = myArray.reduce([Int: Int]()) { 
    var counts = $0    
    counts[$1] = ($0[$1] ?? 0) + 1
    return counts 
}.max { $0.1 < $1.1 }?.0
```

Whether that's considered "unreadable" or "elegant" depends on your feelings towards higher order functions. Nonetheless, here it is as a generic method in an extension on `Array` (so it'll work with any `Hashable` element type):

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    var mode: Element? {
        return self.reduce([Element: Int]()) { 
            var counts = $0
            counts[$1] = ($0[$1] ?? 0) + 1 
            return counts 
        }.max { $0.1 < $1.1 }?.0
    }
}
```

Simply remove the `.0` if you'd rather have a tuple that includes the count of the mode.

Comment: I believe higher order functions to be quite elegant; using `;` to forcibly include as much as possible in single hideously long lines, however, not so much. I edited your answer to increase readability, reverse the edit if you feel it was out of line. (+1 for the solution, the previous applies only to the formatting :)

Comment: @andyvn22 How would this work if myArray had CGPoints? I am getting the error `Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`

Comment: @Hilarious404 That's really a separate question--you need to extend `CGPoint` to add `Hashable` conformance.

Answer (score 6):

My take on it with Swift 5:

```
extension Collection {

    /**
     Returns the most frequent element in the collection.
     */
    func mostFrequent() -> Self.Element?
    where Self.Element: Hashable {
        let counts = self.reduce(into: [:]) {
            return $0[$1, default: 0] += 1
        }

        return counts.max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })?.key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following code. It helps especially when the max count is applicable for 2 or more values.

```
var dictionary = arr.reduce(into: [:]) { counts, number in counts[number, default: 0] += 1}
var max = dictionary.values.max()!
dictionary = dictionary.filter{$0.1 == max}
mode = dictionary.keys.min()!
```

Answer (score 0):

func mostR(num : [Int]) -> (number : Int , totalRepeated : Int)

{
    var numberTofind : Int = 0

```
var total : Int = 0

var dic : [Int : Int] = [:]

for index in num 
{
    if let count = dic[index]
    {
        dic[index] = count + 1 
    }
    else 
    {
        dic[index] = 1
    }

}

var high = dic.values.max()

for (index , count) in dic 
{
   if dic[index] == high 
   {  
       numberTofind = index
       top.append(count)
       total = count
   }

}
return (numberTofind , total)
```

}

var array = [1,22,33,55,4,3,2,0,0,0,0]

var result = mostR(num : [1,22,3,2,43,2,11,0,0,0])

print("the number is (result.number) and its repeated by :(result.totalRepeated)" )

Comment: You should provide a short description of how to implement the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an encapsulated/reusable method.

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    
    /// The mode will be nil when the array is empty.
    var mode: Element? {
        var counts: [Element: Int] = [:]
        forEach { counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }
        if let (value, count) = counts.max(by: {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
            print("\(value) occurs \(count) times")
            return value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
print([3, 4, 5, 6, 6].mode) // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of each occurrence, counting the value of each key in a dictionary. This case is exclusive for integers. Will update this method using generics.

```
func mostCommon(of arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    var dict = [Int:Int]()
    arr.forEach {
        if let count = dict[$0] {
            dict[$0] = count + 1
        } else {
            dict[$0] = 1
        }
    }
    let max = dict.values.max()
    for (_ , value) in dict {
        if value == max {
            return value
        }
     }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: You're using long form where he's using short form, but this is the same solution as the accepted answer, which already uses generics (the same solution is also visible in other answers).