# Does joined() or flatMap(_:) perform better in Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming, swift3

I'm curious about the performance characteristics of `joined()` and `.flatMap(_:)` in flattening a multidimensional array:

```
let array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
let j = Array(array.joined())
let f = array.flatMap{$0}
```

They both flatten the nested `array` into `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Should I prefer one over the other for performance? Also, is there a more readable way to write the calls?

Comment: `joined` is the same as the old `flatten`. So there is nothing new here. You have no new choice to make. If this issue didn't bother you before why should it bother you now?

Comment: @matt Personally I had been using `flatMap` and had never used `flatten`. I saw that `joined` had been added in the Swift changelog and wondered if I should be using it instead of `flatMap`. Then I saw that I would have to wrap the joined call in an `Array` initializer. I suspected that would add a second round of computation and therefore be less efficient. When I wrote the question, I knew that `joined` replaced `flatten`. That said, thank you for explaining why there are two *close* votes. I have reworded the question to remove the implication that the implemenation of joined is new.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### TL; DR

When it comes just to flattening 2D arrays (without any transformations or separators applied, see [@dfri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127525/2976878) for more info about that aspect), `array.flatMap{$0}` and `Array(array.joined())` are both conceptually the same and have similar performance.

---

The main difference between `flatMap(_:)` and `joined()` (note that this isn't a new method, it has [just been renamed from `flatten()`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0133-rename-flatten-to-joined.md)) is that `joined()` is always lazily applied (for arrays, it returns a special [`FlattenBidirectionalCollection<Base>`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/FlattenBidirectionalCollection/)).

Therefore in terms of performance, it makes sense to use `joined()` over `flatMap(_:)` in situations where you only want to iterate over part of a flattened sequence (without applying any transformations). For example:

```
let array2D = [[2, 3], [8, 10], [9, 5], [4, 8]]

if array2D.joined().contains(8) {
    print("contains 8")
} else {
    print("doesn't contain 8")
}
```

Because `joined()` is lazily applied & `contains(_:)` will stop iterating upon finding a match, only the first two inner arrays will have to be 'flattened' to find the element `8` from the 2D array. Although, as [@dfri correctly notes below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115192/should-i-prefer-joined-or-flatmap-in-swift-3/39130099?noredirect=1#comment65609465_39130099), you are also able to lazily apply `flatMap(_:)` through the use of a `LazySequence`/`LazyCollection` – which can be created through the [`lazy`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/Sequence/#-var-lazy_-lazysequence-self) property. This would be ideal for lazily applying both a transformation & flattening a given 2D sequence.

In cases where `joined()` is iterated fully through, it is conceptually no different from using `flatMap{$0}`. Therefore, these are all valid (and conceptually identical) ways of flattening a 2D array:

```
array2D.joined().map{$0}
```

```
Array(array2D.joined())
```

```
array2D.flatMap{$0}
```

---

In terms of performance, [`flatMap(_:)` is documented](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/Sequence/#func--flatmap-segmentofresult_-sequence_-noescape-self-iterator-element-throws-segmentofresult) as having a time-complexity of:

> **O(m + n)**, where m is the length of this sequence and n is the length of the result

This is because [its implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L684) is simply:

```
  public func flatMap<SegmentOfResult : Sequence>(
    _ transform: (${GElement}) throws -> SegmentOfResult
  ) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.${GElement}] {
    var result: [SegmentOfResult.${GElement}] = []
    for element in self {
      result.append(contentsOf: try transform(element))
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

As [`append(contentsOf:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/Array/#func-append-c_-collection-where-c-iterator-element-element-contentsof_-c) has a time-complexity of O(n), where n is the length of sequence to append, we get an overall time-complexity of O(m + n), where m will be total length of all sequences appended, and n is the length of the 2D sequence.

When it comes to `joined()`, there is no documented time-complexity, as it is lazily applied. However, the main bit of source code to consider is [the implementation of `FlattenIterator`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Flatten.swift.gyb#L44), which is used to iterate over the flattened contents of a 2D sequence (which will occur upon using [`map(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/#func-map_) or the [`Array(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/#init_) initialiser with `joined()`).

```
  public mutating func next() -> Base.Element.Iterator.Element? {
    repeat {
      if _fastPath(_inner != nil) {
        let ret = _inner!.next()
        if _fastPath(ret != nil) {
          return ret
        }
      }
      let s = _base.next()
      if _slowPath(s == nil) {
        return nil
      }
      _inner = s!.makeIterator()
    }
    while true
  }
```

Here `_base` is the base 2D sequence, `_inner` is the current iterator from one of the inner sequences, and `_fastPath` & `_slowPath` are hints to the compiler to aid with branch prediction.

Assuming I'm interpreting this code correctly & the full sequence is iterated through, this also has a time complexity of O(m + n), where m is the length of the sequence, and n is the length of the result. This is because it goes through each outer iterator and each inner iterator to get the flattened elements.

So, performance wise, `Array(array.joined())` and `array.flatMap{$0}` both have the same time complexity.

If we run a quick benchmark in a debug build (Swift 3.1):

```
import QuartzCore

func benchmark(repeatCount:Int = 1, name:String? = nil, closure:() -> ()) {
    let d = CACurrentMediaTime()
    for _ in 0..<repeatCount {
        closure()
    }
    let d1 = CACurrentMediaTime()-d
    print("Benchmark of \(name ?? "closure") took \(d1) seconds")
}

let arr = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: 1000), count: 1000)

benchmark {
    _ = arr.flatMap{$0} // 0.00744s
}

benchmark {
    _ = Array(arr.joined()) // 0.525s
}

benchmark {
    _ = arr.joined().map{$0} // 1.421s
}
```

`flatMap(_:)` appears to be the fastest. I suspect that  `joined()` being slower could be due to the branching that occurs within the `FlattenIterator` (although the hints to the compiler minimise this cost) – although just why `map(_:)` is so slow, I'm not too sure. Would certainly be interested to know if anyone else knows more about this.

However, in an optimised build, the compiler is able to optimise away this big performance difference; giving all three options comparable speed, although `flatMap(_:)` is still fastest by a fraction of a second:

```
let arr = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: 10000), count: 1000)

benchmark {
    let result = arr.flatMap{$0} // 0.0910s
    print(result.count)
}

benchmark {
    let result = Array(arr.joined()) // 0.118s
    print(result.count)
}

benchmark {
    let result = arr.joined().map{$0} // 0.149s
    print(result.count)
}
```

(Note that the order in which the tests are performed can affect the results – both of above results are an average from performing the tests in the various different orders)

Comment: Nice answer! Note that you can apply `flatMap` and `map` lazily by prefixing them with `lazy.` (e.g. `arr.lazy.flatMap{$0}`). Can't explain why the map version `map` is seemingly so much slower, but I'll double check (you most likely knows this): make sure to perform benchmarking in an actual project and not in a playground.

Comment: @dfri Great point! Completely forgot about `LazySequence`/`LazyCollection`s – I have updated my answer to note this, thanks for mentioning it. The benchmark was indeed performed in a full project with no compiler opmisations (I never use playgrounds) :)

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarking @Hamish. That is a cool snippet of code to keep handy! Also, thanks for digging into the implementation details

Comment: Happy to help @BenMorrow :)

Comment: I did a simple test, flatMap is much faster than joined.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Swiftdoc.org documentation of `Array` (Swift 3.0/dev)](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/Array) we read [**emphasis mine**]:

> ```
> func flatMap<SegmentOfResult : Sequence>(_: @noescape (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult)
> ```
>
> Returns an array containing the concatenated results of calling the
>   given transformation with each element of this sequence.
>
> ...
>
> In fact, `s.flatMap(transform)` **is equivalent to** `Array(s.map(transform).flatten())`.

We may also take a look at the actual implementations of the two in the Swift source code (from which Swiftdoc is generated ...)

- [swift/stdlib/public/core/Join.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Join.swift)
- [swift/stdlib/public/core/FlatMap.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FlatMap.swift)

Most noteably the latter source file, where the `flatMap` implementations where the used closure (`transform`) does not yield and optional value (as is the case here) are all described as

> ```
> /// Returns the concatenated results of mapping `transform` over
> /// `self`.  Equivalent to 
> ///
> ///     self.map(transform).joined()
> ```

From the above (assuming the compiler can be clever w.r.t. a simple over self `{ $0 }` `transform`), it would seem as if performance-wise, the two alternatives should be equivalent, but `joined` does, imo, better show the *intent* of the operation.

---

In addition to intent in semantics, there is one apparent use case where `joined` is preferable over (and not entirely comparable to) `flatMap`: using `joined` with it's `init(separator:)` initializer to join sequences with a separator:

```
let array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
let j = Array(array.joined(separator: [42]))

print(j) // [1, 2, 3, 42, 4, 5, 6, 42, 7, 8, 9]
```

The corresponding result using `flatMap` is not really as neat, as we explicitly need to remove the final additional separator *after* the `flatMap` operation (two different use cases, with or without trailing separator)

```
let f = Array(array.flatMap{ $0 + [42] }.dropLast())
print(f) // [1, 2, 3, 42, 4, 5, 6, 42, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

See also a somewhat outdated post of Erica Sadun dicussing `flatMap` vs. `flatten()` (note: `joined()` was named `flatten()` in Swift < 3).

- [Erica Sadun- Beta 6: flatten #swiftlang](http://ericasadun.com/2015/08/30/beta-6-flatten-swiftlang/)

Comment: Swift 2.x and older are "Swift <3" now? Such nostalgia.

Comment: @rickster ah don't remove my <{whitespace with extra intent}3! ;) But yes indeed, hopefully some time now though before we need to apply "Swift<4" statements.

Comment: Thank you for your research, @dfri. I agree that `.joined()` feels better to express intent. I just wish I didn't have to wrap it in the `Array()` initializer. Such is the price to pay for the added lazy benefit I suppose