# Why `joined()` is much slower than `flatMap()`?

Tags: swift

I want to join a large array with `joined()`, and I found this method is very slow, it is much slower than `flatMap()`, here is the code to reproduce it.

As you can see, `joined` takes around 0.26s, `flatMap` takes around 0.0064s, do you know why this happened?

```swift
import Foundation

var datas = [Data]()
var count = 0
(0...10000).forEach { _ in
    let data = """
            public struct FlattenSequence<Base: Sequence> where Base.Element: Sequence {
            public struct FlattenSequence<Base: Sequence> where Base.Element: Sequence {
            """.data(using: .utf8)!
    datas.append(data)
    count += data.count
}



// 1st approach, it takes 0.0049s, around 40 times faster than the 2nd approach.
let start1 = Date()
var wholeData1 = Data(capacity: count)
datas.forEach {
    wholeData1.append($0)
}
print("Time 1: \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start1))")

// 2nd approach, it takes 0.26s,
let start2 = Date()
let wholeData2 = Data.init(datas.joined())
print("Time 2: \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start2))")

// 3rd approach, it takes 0.0064s
let start3 = Date()
let wholeData3 = Data.init(datas.flatMap { $0 })
print("Time 3: \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start3))")

print(wholeData1 == wholeData2)
print(wholeData1 == wholeData3)
print(count)
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115192/does-joined-or-flatmap-perform-better-in-swift-3

Comment: Usually caveat: are you testing this outside of a playground with release mode enabled?

Comment: @Alexander The difference is smaller in release mode, but flatMap is still much faster.

Comment: Might be caused by how the `Data` initializer handles the array of `Data` returned by `flatMap` versus the `FlattenSequence` returned by `joined()`

Comment: For some use cases the best option will be chaining: https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chain.md

Answer (score 0):

After I read this doc

```
/// The `joined` method is always lazy, but does not implicitly
/// confer laziness on algorithms applied to its result.  In other
/// words, for ordinary sequences `s`:
///
/// * `s.joined()` does not create new storage
/// * `s.joined().map(f)` maps eagerly and returns a new array
/// * `s.lazy.joined().map(f)` maps lazily and return
```

I did some more test, and I have found out the performance of `datas.lazy.flatMap { $0 }`, `datas.lazy.joined()`, `datas.joined()` is quite similar, which means the slowness is caused by laziness.

But I still don't understand why swift decide to make `joined` method be always lazy, we already have a `LazySequence`, we can always call an array method lazily by `array.lazy.method`.

IMHO, the better option would be remove the laziness from `joined`, and we can still call it lazily by `array.lazy.joined()`.