# How to arrange a CGPoint array in order of the most frequent points

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift3, mapping

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416347/swift-3-getting-the-most-frequent-value-of-an-array)
which showed how to get the most frequent value of an array for say, integers in the following way:

```
let myArray = [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2]

// Create dictionary to map value to count   
var counts = [Int: Int]()

// Count the values with using forEach    
myArray.forEach { counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }

// Find the most frequent value and its count with max(isOrderedBefore:)    
if let (value, count) = counts.max(isOrderedBefore: {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
    print("\(value) occurs \(count) times")
}
```

I want to achieve the same result for an array of `CGPoints`, this is a bit different. I tried using the same code and got an error:

```
Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
```

at the line

```
var counts = [CGPoint: Int]()
```

and an error

```
Value of type 'CGPoint' has no member '1'
```

at the line

```
if let (value, count) = counts.max(isOrderedBefore: {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
```

How can I arrange the CGPoint array in order of frequency and print say, a tuple with the value and the number of time it appears?

Comment: Here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148763/extending-cgpoint-to-conform-to-hashable are some ideas about making CGPoint Hashable.

Comment: If the coordinates are not integers then the limited precision of binary floating point numbers might become an issue. As an example, `CGPoint(x: 0.1 + 0.2, y: 0)` is *different* from `CGPoint(x: 0.3, y: 0)`.

Comment: @MartinR why not just use the CGPoint debugDescription to create the dictionary ? `var counts = [String: Int]()
myArray.forEach { counts[$0.debugDescription] = (counts[$0.debugDescription] ?? 0) + 1 }
if let (value, count) = counts.max(by: {$0.value < $1.value}) {
    print("\(value) occurs \(count) times")
}` https://gist.github.com/leodabus/b109b2ca9633c44974399a771690fe1d

Comment: @LeoDabus: Yes, you can do that, but then you rely on an undocumented debugDescription format. Also computing string hash values is (as far as I know) relatively "expensive", using a hash value computed from the x/y coordinates should be faster.

Comment: @MartinR  thank you

Answer (score 1):

What this line of error means :

> Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

is that you can't use `CGPoint` objects as keys to a dictionary.

The workaround Leo Dabus mentioned in comments should work well: use the debug description (`String`) of your `CGPoint` objects as keys to the dictionary of `counts`:

```
var counts = [String: Int]() 

myArray.forEach { counts[$0.debugDescription] = (counts[$0.debugDescription] ?? 0) + 1 } 

if let (value, count) = counts.max(by: {$0.value < $1.value}) { 
  print("\(value) occurs \(count) times") 
}
```