# What to do for a frequent value in array when there are no frequent values

Tags: arrays, swift, count, mutable

I followed the answers from [Swift 3: Getting the most frequent value of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416347/swift-3-getting-the-most-frequent-value-of-an-array)

There are 2 answer that I tried

1. @vacawama
2. @appzYourLife

**Both of their answers return the same result if an array has a frequent recurring value:**

```
var frequentValue = [1, 2, 2, 4]

//1. vacawama's code
var counts = [Int:Int]()
frequentValue.forEach{ counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1}
if let (value, count) = counts.maxElement({$0.1 < $1.1}){
    print("The result is: \(value)")
}
prints *The result is: 2*

//2. appzYourLife's code
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: frequentValue)
let most = countedSet.maxElement({countedSet.countForObject($0) < countedSet.countForObject($1)})
print("The result is: \(most!)")
*prints The result is: 2*
```

**What I notice is if there is no frequent value their code will give different results.**

```
var noFrequentValue = [1, 2, 3, 4]

//1. vacawama's code
prints *The result is: 2*

//2. appzYourLife's code
*prints The result is: 3*
```

**But the thing is with the noFrequentValue if the numbers inside the array mutate the results constantly change**

```
noFrequentValue = [1, 4]
//1. vacawama's code 
prints The result is: 4

//2. appzYourLife's code
prints The result is: 1

noFrequentValue = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
//1. vacawama's code 
prints The result is: 5

//2. appzYourLife's code
prints The result is: 7

noFrequentValue = [1, 2, 3, 0, etc...]
```

**Another thing I tried was putting 2 or more values inside the array with identical frequent values**

```
multipleFrequentValues = [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9]
//1. vacawama's code 
prints The result is: 7

//2. appzYourLife's code
prints The result is: 7

multipleFrequentValues = [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9 , 0, 0]
//1. vacawama's code 
prints The result is: 5

//2. appzYourLife's code
prints The result is: 7

multipleFrequentValues = [2, 2, 8, 8]
//1. vacawama's code 
prints The result is: 2

//2. appzYourLife's code
prints The result is: 8
```

**Why is their code giving different results when there isn't a frequent value vs when there are several?**

**What's a good default for both situations when there isn't a frequent value?**

Comment: FYI, the most common value in a data set is called the [*mode*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mode.html) of the data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an expanded version of my original answer.  It gives much more information.

```
var frequentValue = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]

var counts = [Int : Int]()

frequentValue.forEach { counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }
if let (_, count) = counts.max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 }) {
    if count == 1 {
        print("There are no repeated items.")
    } else {
        let all = counts.flatMap { $1 == count ? $0 : nil }
        if all.count == 1 {
            print("The most frequent item \(all.first!) is repeated \(count) times.")
        } else {
            print("The items \(all.sorted()) are repeated \(count) times each.")
        }
    }
} else {
    print("The array is empty.")
}
```

Output:

> ```
> The items [1, 3] are repeated 2 times each.
> ```

Comment: good answer! thanks :) How'd you know that I mentioned you  in a post?

Comment: I'm psychic. :-)  Actually, I just was reading new questions and stumbled upon yours.

Comment: lmao, the psychic joke was funny

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions hold counts in unordered structures. One solution uses a dictionary, the other one uses a set. Neither a dictionary or a set keep values ordered. When trying to get the value with the highest count, a random value is returned.

To fix it, you would have to use a structure that can keep values ordered, e.g. an array.

A reasonable solution depends on the requirements. For example, you could take all the values with the highest count and take the lowest of them or the highest of them or the first one that appears in the original array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was assuming the results were random but I wasn't sure. It makes sense with both collections being unordered. I'm going to try your advice and see what happens.