# Finding mode of array of strings in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, mode

I'm new to Swift, using Xcode version 8.3. I have an array of strings and I'm trying to find the mode value of the array.

I've tried the suggested code from this Stack Overflow post (and have searched for others): [Swift 3: Getting the most frequent value of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416347/swift-3-getting-the-most-frequent-value-of-an-array)

but I'm not getting it to work.

Upon trying NSCountedSet:

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: myArray)
let mostFrequent = countedSet.max { countedSet.count(for: $0) < 
countedSet.count(for: $1) }
```

the console prints "nil" upon running,  perhaps because my arrays are arrays of strings? It also seems the .max is no longer valid in my version of Xcode. I'm unsure.

I also tried using "hashable" and "reduce" and cannot get these to work. I get the error "declaration is only valid at file scope":

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
                                var mode: Element? {
                                    return self.reduce([Element: Int]()) {
                                        var counts = $0
                                        counts[$1] = ($0[$1] ?? 0) + 1
                                        return counts 
                                        }.max { $0.1 < $1.1 }?.0
                                }
                            }
```

I would like to store the mode as a value, so I don't know that using a dictionary would be appropriate.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: That's a pretty decent way to do it. The error is occurring because you're probably trying to declare this extension within the scope of another class/struct/enum/extension. As the error suggests, the declaration of that extension must be in the file scope

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of arrays, the easiest thing will be to use `joined` to collapse them into a simple array:

```
let samples = [[ 1, 2, 3 ], [4, 5, 6, 1]]
let flattened = [Int](samples.joined())
let counted = NSCountedSet(array:flattened)
let max = counted.max { counted.count(for: $0) < counted.count(for: $1) }
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for guidance on doing it with strings, not Ints