# Calculation mode in an array (more than one Mode)

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a problem to calculate Mode (most frequent number in an array) in swift. 
For example, in this code

```
func mostFrequent(array: [Int]) -> (value: Int, count: Int)?
{
    var counts = [Int: Int]()

    array.forEach { counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }

    if let (value, count) = counts.max(by: {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
        return (value, count)
    }

    return nil
}

if let result = mostFrequent(array: [2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6]) {
    print("\(result.value) is repeated \(result.count) times")    
}
```

Print: 2 is repeated 3 times

I can find the first most frequent number, which is 2 that repeated 3 times. But as you can see if there is another number that also repeated 3 times, i can not see it by using this function. 
For example, In my array of numbers, 2 is repeated 3 times and hence is the Mode. But there is two Modes, which is 4 that also repeated 3 times. I want this function show both of modes. Could anyone help me to guide me to how to do it?

Comment: return `value: [Int]` instead?

Comment: @zerkms No actually, it doesn’t work. It would be:

    [2] is repated 3 times

Comment: Well, you implemented it wrong then.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem that i could not find any way to fix it. I have tried many ways but each of them doesnt really work

Comment: First - ensure you understand how to implement it: imagine you're given a collection of numbers on piece of paper and you should manually solve the problem, using your paper and pen only. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to filter your results that are equal to the max count and map their keys:

```
func mostFrequent(array: [Int]) -> (mostFrequent: [Int], count: Int)? {
    var counts: [Int: Int] = [:]
        
    array.forEach { counts[$0] = (counts[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }
    if let count = counts.max(by: {$0.value < $1.value})?.value {
        return (counts.compactMap { $0.value == count ? $0.key : nil }, count)
    }
    return nil
}
```

---

```
if let result = mostFrequent(array: [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6]) {
    print(result) // "(mostFrequent: [2, 4], count: 3)\n"
}
```

---

edit/update:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    var frequency: [Element: Int] { reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 } }
    var mostFrequent: (mostFrequent: [Element], count: Int)? {
        guard let maxCount = frequency.values.max() else { return nil }
        return (frequency.compactMap { $0.value == maxCount ? $0.key : nil }, maxCount)
    }
}
```

---

usage:

```
let array = [2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6]
if let mostFrequent = array.mostFrequent {
    print("Most frequent", mostFrequent)
}
```

---

This will print:

> Most frequent (mostFrequent: [2, 4], count: 3)

Comment: Thank you very much dear Leo, it works prefectly. You are just awesome

Comment: @user9217262 Check my last edit. You should use the dictionary tuple names `(key, value)` instead of `.0` and `.1`.

Comment: Would you mind if I updated this to use the new [`Dictionary.init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init) which was introduced since this answer we added? Or perhaps `reduce(into:)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38416464/3141234

Answer (score 0):

I made my own function, which is a bit jankier and probably has worse performance, but I just wanted to post this if someone wanted a more easily adjustable function. In my opinion, it returns a clean set of values and it has clear comments for what each part does.

```
 import Foundation

 func Mode( _ arr: [Double] ) -> ( [Double], Int ) {
     var valueFrequencies = [Double : Int]() // dict. of number and its frequency.
     for i in arr { // for each value in data set
       if !valueFrequencies.keys.contains(i) { // if value has not occurred yet then...
         valueFrequencies[i] = 1 // create a key of that number with a frequency of 1.
       } else { // or if that value has already occurred before then...
           valueFrequencies[i]! += 1 // increase the frequency each time it occurs.
         }
     }
     guard let maxFrequency = valueFrequencies.values.max() else{return ([],0)} // unwrap the mode frequency or return an empty tuple.
     var modes = [Double]() // array for the mode number(s).
     for key in valueFrequencies.keys { // for each key in dict
       if Double(valueFrequencies[key]!) == Double(maxFrequency) { // if the number's frequency is equal to the mode frequency then...
         modes.append(key) // add number to modes array.
       }
     }
     return (modes,maxFrequency) // return array of mode(s) and the mode frequency.
   }

   let dataSet:[Double] = [1,3, 9, 8, 9, 5, 2, 5, 6]
   print(Mode(dataSet)) // Outputs: ([5.0, 9.0], 2)
   print(Mode(dataSet).0) // Outputs: [5.0, 9.0] note: this code does not sort the modes. Values are from a dict. so the order is random.
   print(Mode(dataSet).1) // Outputs: 2
```